# Braced-init-lists and function template type deduction order

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction, list-initialization

I have a question regarding the function template parameter type deduction procedure.

Take this example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("path/to/file");
    std::vector<int> vec(std::istream_iterator<int>{file},{}); // <- This part
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand things correctly, the second parameter is deduced to be of type `std::istream_iterator` of which the default constructor is called.

The appropriate `std::vector` constructor is declared as:

```
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Since the first parameter type is deduced as `std::istream_iterator<int>` the second parameter is deduced as `std::istream_iterator<int>` too and so the uniform initialization semantics can be applied. What I have no idea about is at what order the type deduction happens. I would really appreciate some info on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work? If so the first one must be deducted first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's use an even simpler example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T, T);

foo(42, {});
```

The function call has two arguments:

- a prvalue expression of type `int` (an integer literal)
- a *braced-init-list* `{}`

The latter, `{}`, can be part of an *expression-list* but it is not an *expression* itself. An *expression-list* is defined as an *initializer-list*. *braced-init-lists* do not have a type.

Template type deduction is done for each function parameter individually [temp.deduct.type]/2. [temp.deduct.call]/1 states about type deduction for a function parameter `P`:

> If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives
>   `std::initializer_list<`*P'*`>` for some *P'* and the argument is an
>   initializer list, then deduction is performed instead for each element
>   of the initializer list, taking *P'* as a function template parameter
>   type and the initializer element as its argument. **Otherwise, an
>   initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a
>   non-deduced context.** [emphasis mine]

So in the call `foo(42, {});` the `T` will not be deduced from the second argument `{}`. However, `T` can be deduced from the first argument.

In general, we can deduce `T` from multiple function parameters. In that case, the deduced types have to match exactly [temp.deduct.type]/2. There is no problem if the type is only deduced from one function parameter but used elsewhere (in another function parameter that is in a non-deduced context, in the return type etc). Type deduction can fail e.g. when a template parameter cannot be deduced from *any* function parameter and is not set explicitly.

After deduction, `T` will be substituted by `int`, producing a function signature similar to:

```
void foo<int>(int, int);
```

This function can be called with the two arguments `42` and `{}`. The latter will perform a copy-list-initialization leading to a value-initialization of the second parameter.

Comment: This is more or less how I was seeing it intuitively. Thanks for clearing things up.